# "openssl ca" throws out subject fields other than CN

Tags: openssl, x509, self-signed, certificate-authority

So I have the following command to generate a CSR with fancy subject:

```
% keytool -certreq \
          -dname "emailAddress=${email_address}, CN=${artifact}, OU=Dev, O=Pany, C=UK" \
          -alias ${artifact} -file ${artifact}.csr -keypass ${pwd} -keystore ${artifact}.jks -storepass ${pwd}
% openssl x509 -text -in ${artifact}.csr
    Subject: C = UK, O = AbbeyCross, OU = Dev, CN = alamar, emailAddress = alamar@pany.com
```

But then I sign it with `openssl ca` and end up with a certificate that has truncated subject

```
% openssl ca -config ca/${ca_name}.cnf \
             -startdate ${startdate} -enddate ${enddate} \
             -batch -out ${artifact}.pem -infiles ${artifact}.csr
% openssl x509 -text -in ${artifact}.pem | grep Subject
    Subject: CN = alamar
```

Note how all the fancy fields from Subject, such as e-mail, are gone.

**Where did they go? How do I bring them back?** `openssl ca` manpage is mostly useless. I can see there is an option `-noemailDN`, but it does not explain why OU and O also evaporated from Subject. I also know there's `-subj` but it would require re-encoding the same stuff into a different format for no apparent reason, and does not explain where the Subject went in the first place.

Comment: In your config file [check the section pointed to by the item `policy` in the CA section](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-ca.html#POLICY-FORMAT) (since you didn't use commandline option `-policy` which would override the config item). PS: instead of grepping you can do `openssl x509 -in $certfile -noout -subject`. But this is not programming or development.

Comment: `-preserveDN` seems to be the way to go - care to turn your comment into answer so that it may be accepted?